# Sort List of Objects by values from array;

Tags: java, arrays, list, sorting

I have a `List<Brand> categories;` with 1000+ items.

For each item from the list I have `id`, to get that I use `categories.getId();`

And I have an array `int[] sortedIdArr = {4,53,102,403,110,5,6,8,12};`

I would like to sort my `categories` list and make order by `id` how it is in `sortedIdArr`. 
How can I implement that ?

```
private void sortBrandsById(List<Brand> categories) {
    Collections.sort(categories, new Comparator<Brand>() {
        public int compare(Brand o1, Brand o2) {

        }
    });    
}
```

Can I use `Collections.sort` ?

Comment: Check the index of both IDs in `sortedIdArr` and compare these indices. If the index of `o1-ID` is smaller than `o2-ID`, then it should return `1`, `-1` of smaller and `0` if equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you would use `Collections.sort`, or the equivalent idioms in Java 8 if applicable, or a sorted `Collection` such as `TreeSet`.

**However** in this case you want to follow a pre-defined order, dictated by your `sortedIdArr` array.

One way to achieve that is to use a linked collection (e.g. a `LinkedHashSet`).

Then you iterate your `sortedIdArr` array, and search your `List<Brand>` for an object with the given ID.

If found, you add the `Brand` object with the given ID to your `LinkedHashSet`, which will retain the insertion order.

Note that if an ID is not found, your `Set` will not exactly "match" the array.

**Self-enclosed example, using Java 8**

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Set;


public class Main {

    // simplified Brand pojo
    static class Brand {
        int id;
        public Brand(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        // for output clarity
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("Brand: %d", id);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // simplified ID list
        int[] sortedIdArr = {4,53,102};
        // "randomly" ordered Brand list
        final List<Brand> categories = new ArrayList<Brand>() {  
            {
                add(new Brand(1));
                add(new Brand(102));
                add(new Brand(53));
                add(new Brand(4));
                add(new Brand(0));
            }
        };
        // destination: linked set
        Set<Brand> linked = new LinkedHashSet<Brand>();
        // streaming the ID array in order
        Arrays.stream(sortedIdArr)
            .forEach((i) -> {
                // retrieving a Brand with same ID as the current
                // from the "randomly" ordered list
                Optional<Brand> toAdd = categories.stream()
                .filter((b) -> b.getId() == i)
                .findFirst();
                // making sure there's one
                if (toAdd.isPresent()) {
                    // adding to linked set
                    linked.add(toAdd.get());
                }
            }
        );
        System.out.println(linked);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
[Brand: 4, Brand: 53, Brand: 102]
```

**Imperative idiom for older Java versions**

```
for (int i: sortedIdArr) {
    for (Brand b: categories) {
        // assuming no nulls
        if (b.getId() == i) {
            linked.add(b);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice approach, but Is it real to avoid java 8 ? I`m using this code in android, and currently there is problems with java 8.

Comment: @VLeonovs if you're on Android you can forget the Java 8 idioms, yes :) But you can convert it to Java 6-styled approach relatively easily - see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** you can use the `Collections.sort()`

**To sort your `Brand` using `id` :**

```
public int compare(Brand o1, Brand o2) {
   return o1.getId().compareTo(o2.getId());
}
```

**To sort your `Brand` using the array of id `sortedIdArr`  :**

Implement the `Comparator` Class :

```
class C implements Comparator<A> {

    int[] idOrder;

    public C(int[] idOrder) {
        super();
        this.idOrder = idOrder;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(A o1, A o2) {

        Integer indexofO1 = Arrays.binarySearch(idOrder, o1.getId());
        Integer indexofO2 = Arrays.binarySearch(idOrder, o2.getId());
        return indexofO1.compareTo(indexofO2);
    }
}
```

> The key idea here is to inverse the process and compare using the index of the id instead of the id itself !

To use it :

```
Collections.sort(list, new C (idOrder));
```

**Test Example :**

```
int[] idOrder = new int [] {3,1,2};
List<A> list = new ArrayList<>();

list.add(new A(1));
list.add(new A(2));
list.add(new A(3));

System.out.println(list);
//Output : [A [id=1], A [id=2], A [id=3]]

Collections.sort(list, new C(idOrder));

System.out.println(list);
//Output : [A [id=3], A [id=1], A [id=2]]
```

Comment: He wants to sort the category list by the order of ids which are in the `sortedIdArr`. Your approach sort the list by the Brand's id property in an ascending way. It has nothing to do with the order of ids listed in `sortedIdArr`.

Comment: Thks gays .. i updated my answer to solve the **sortedIdArr problem** :) .. you can check it

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `Collections.sort(...)` but I strongly recommend not to go for `Comparator` method in this situation with this number of items in your list.

You can have a loop on your `List<Brand> categories` and add them in a `HashMap<Integer,Brand>` named tempMap. Then use it for lookup them in the order of your `sortedIdArr` array. Change your sort method like this:

```
private void sortBrandsById(List<Brand> categories, int [] sortedIdArr) {
    HashMap<Integer,Brand> tempMap = new HashMap<Integer, Brand>(categories.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < categories.size(); i++) {
        tempMap.put(categories.get(i).getId(), categories.get(i));
    }
    categories = new ArrayList<Brand>(sortedIdArr.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < sortedIdArr.length; i++) {
        categories.add(tempMap.get(sortedIdArr[i]));
    }
}
```

This way of sorting is from order `O(n)` for creating the `tempMap` + `O(n)` for recreating the `category` list. Although, the `O(1)` is not guaranteed for HashMap's get/put operations, java's decent hashing implementation very good and reliable. So the total complexity can not be very greater than `O(n)`. At least it is very better than `O(n^2)`. Time complexity is very important and I don't think you can find a way better than something very near `O(n)` complexity.

Hope this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code(You need the Apache commons lang jar-otherwise you have to iterate through your array to find the index).

```
private static void sortBrandsById(List<Brand> categories,int[] array) {


            Collections.sort(categories, new Comparator<Brand>() {
                public int compare(Brand o1, Brand o2) {                            

    return ArrayUtils.indexOf(array,o1.getId())-ArrayUtils.indexOf(array,o2.getId());
                }
            });    
        }
```

If you are able to put your predefined sorting order in a list not in an array , it will be much easier.